# Symlnk failed in strange way on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I tried to create a symlink for the external SD on a Galaxy S3 as I have done it on my HTC M8 previously. I tried with terminal emulator in command line, with Root Explorer and with Solid Explorer. It always worked and they were fully operational – but when I rebooted the device they are always lost, no track of the symlink previously created. Could someone explain, what is happening and how to correct that ? Thank you.

I forgot, my device is GT-9300 French running Android 4.3

Comment: Very much depends on where you wanted to create the symlink. A good guess: in the root FS? That would explain, as that FS is built up from a RAM disk on boot. You'd need to either manipulate the boot-image then – or use some `init.d` script to create the symlink on each boot. Doing it with an app like *Tasker* would be another approach.

Comment: @Izzy, that is a valid answer. Please make it one.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Yes, sir – done so, with a few more details making it a valid *and detailed* answer :) Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Thanks for idea. I have it done with init.d after implementing on my stock ROM. I also did with Tasker. Both worked very well. I prefer init;d as it is a system solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very much depends on where you wanted to create the symlink. A good guess: in the root file-system? That would explain the behaviour:

Android uses an [initial RAM-disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) (aka "boot-image") on startup, from which it creates the rootFS (and several other things) anew each time – so changes to the root file-system don't survive a boot. That leaves you with at least two or three options:

- **manipulate the boot-image:** only if you have the experience. Getting that wrong, and you might have to flash a fresh ROM (worst case; keeping the original, you could replace it via [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) – but the try-and-err process might take a while)
- **use some `init.d` script to create the symlink on each boot:** Requires your device/ROM to support the [init.d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) system (not all do). Again, a "borked script" might screw your boot process; but you could verify your script (running it manually) before placing it into `init.d`, and doing so keeps the risk level very low.
- **Using an app-based solution:** apps like [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) offer to run stuff as soon as boot is completed.